# JS function called from PHP works well in Chrome but it doesn't in Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, html, browser

I have this simple code that allow users to search for certain content within a webpage. The code works well in Chrome and Opera but it does not in Firefox and Explorer. In this last two browsers mentioned, once the form is posted, the page just refreshes itself instead of redirecting to the result page.

What would I need to add or modify in order to make this work in all major browsers?

Thank's for you attention.

The code:

```
<?php
if($_POST[search2]){

    if(!empty($_POST[text_search])){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.open('search_results.php?q=".$_POST[text_search]."','_parent'); </script>";
    }else{
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert ('You must enter something'); </script>";
    }   
}
?>
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="" name="formsearch">
        <input name="text_search" class="input_search" type="text" placeholder="Enter your search">
        <input type="image" src="search.png" id="search2" value="search" name="search2"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For one you are putting the script tag outside of <html> which isn't good. You should put that php code either in <head> or <body>

Comment: shouldn't this $_POST[search2] be $_POST['search2']

Comment: can you just change the location.href instead of using popups?

Comment: @Satya It'll likely work but will throw a notice (something about constant not existing, assuming "search2") and is bad-practice. I doubt this is causing the browser inconsistency, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input type="image" defines an image as a submit button but never carry the value in the post array to server. Alternative to use image as submit, try to use button.

Replace

```
<input type="image" src="search.png" id="search2" value="search" name="search2"/>
```

With

```
<button type="submit" name="search2" value="search"><img src="search.png" alt="search"></button>
```

Also use quotes for $_POST elements.

```
if($_POST['search2']){

if(!empty($_POST['text_search'])){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.open('search_results.php?q=".$_POST['text_search']."','_parent'); </script>";
}else{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert ('You must enter something'); </script>";
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
if($_POST['search2']){

    if(!empty($_POST['text_search'])){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.open('search_results.php?q=".$_POST['text_search']."','_parent'); </script>";
    }else{
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert ('You must enter something'); </script>";
    }   
}
?>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="" name="formsearch">
        <input name="text_search" class="input_search" type="text" placeholder="Enter your search">
        <input type="image" src="search.png" id="search2" value="search" name="search2"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

You just need to put your php tag that generates the JS between . 
and I also put quote in the $_POST index.

Comment: Thank you, besides that I had to replace "input type="image"" for "button type="submit"" to make ir work